# How to Use Parse.com Lists in Tabs?

Tags: java, android, oop, parse-platform, virtual

I've got the following function:

```
public static class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false );

        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>( this, "Todo" );
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
        mainAdapter.setImageKey("image");

        // Initialize ListView and set initial view to mainAdapter
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The errors returned are:

The constructor ParseQueryAdapter(MainActivity.ListFragment, String) is undefined  MainActivity.java

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity    MainActivity.java

I can assume that the first one due to the change of the object of type **this** but I would like a more seasoned input on the correct fix.

The second error though thoroughly confounds as it appears to be valid to my eyes.

Appreciate any input.

Comment: Try removing the `static` modifier from your class definition.

Comment: That's great, appreciate it.  Assuming that won't cause unforeseen problems down the road?  What about the proper way to instantiate the constructor from within this object type it isn't expecting?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What error do you get after removing `static`?

Comment: I'm sorry the SO formatter broke my line breaks.  The first error is still there, you got the second one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Change the instantiation of `ParseQueryAdapter` as follows.  The code is in a `Fragment`, but `ParseQueryAdapter` requires a `Context` object.

```
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>( this.getActivity(), "Todo" );
```

---

**2)** Remove the `static` modifier from your class definition.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear that there were two different errors.  You got the second one, any idea what's causing the first?  I believe they both fall under the scope of porting standard ListView code to Tabbed ListView so I'm hoping to get both answers if I can.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the solution for the other error.

Comment: After compiling, I get a crash from Null Pointer on mainAdapter :\ java.lang.NullPointerException ... at com.example.testapp.MainActivity$ListFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java) and breakpoints reveal that the offending line is listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter); which worked in the Parse.com tutorial...

Comment: @Puck you need to post a new question to resolve the new issue, as the original compilation issue is resolved. Include the updated code and a reference to the tutorial you are following.

Comment: It's possible that you're right and this is a mistake I've made, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.  Thanks again.